# In my wired LAN, when i connect ethernet cable to a particular PC Internet goes for all other system

Tags: internet, lan

In my college Lab all PCs are connected through wired LAN. When i connect Ethernet cable to to a particular PC (say PC-A) then we do not get internet connection in all other PCs. So every time i have to remove the cable from PC-A then internet comes automatically in all computers. Actually PC-A has no special network configuration (or not running any special service except virtual box with host-only-adapter(I don't think that it will affect)).
Any suggestion...

Comment: Troubleshoot. *Why* don't other computers get an Internet connection? Can they still ping the default router? Can they still populate their ARP caches?

Answer (score 0):

Check network settings and make sure that they *match* the settings on the other computers in the Lab.

If the settings are DHCP (automatic) then make sure the DHCP server has settings that allow an IP to be received.

If the lab uses static IP:s then make sure the IP set at "PC-A" isn't a duplicate of any other PCs.